# ft-lbs to ft-lbs3 or newtons as well as strength of metal

Tags: motors, gears

I am trying to figure out how much torque this piece of metal that I have can deal with before breaking.

Are there any tools online that can help me calculate these items?

The hardness of this iron is 167-229Ha
tensile strength is >=58kg/mm2
elasticity is >= 45%
density is 0.785

Currently the pipe is a hexagaon that's 55mm in diameter, then the ends are cylinders that are 40mm in diameter.

Since this is early in the design phase I'd like to be able to adjust torque and the size of the metal pipe so that it wouldn't break.

Currently I have 1200RPM 15HP motor that I have reduced down to 85RPM which if I calculated correctly should be around 926 ft-lbs of torque.

Are there any tools that will help me convert from ft-lbs to lbs-ft3 or calculate these values?
[one such online calculator.](http://www.endmemo.com/sconvert/kg_m3lb_ft3.php)

Comment: Where do you get ft-lbs3 ??

Comment: I was looking at some online calculators although I think it was lbs-ft3. I'll edit that.

Comment: ft-lbs is a torque ie force * distance same as Nm Newton metres is.

Comment: For tensile strength, kg/mm^2 does not make sense.  This is typically expressed in Pa, i.e. N/m^2.  Did you maybe start with a strength in lbf/in^2 and then convert pounds to kg?  If so, you should have converted pounds to Newtons, as this is a force not a mass.

Comment: odd as that unit is its not at all unusual come across such in published data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/torsion-shafts-d_947.html) and [this page](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/Structures.d/IAST.Lect07.d/IAST.Lect07.pdf) would be good places to get you started.

In addition to my comment above, you'll probably want to design to the yield strength and not the ultimate tensile strength.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you very much!

Comment: a link only answer can suffer from link "rot" - please quote the relevant material in the body of your answer for the future.